# Formatting date from a dataframe of strings

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, date, format

I have data that looks like this:

```
0 2/18/2020
1 9/30/2019
```

Each line is a str

I want it to keep its type (string, not datetime) but to look like this:

```
0 2020-02-18
1 2019-09-30
```

How can I achieve this format for all rows in the dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` to separate the `MM`, `DD`, and `YYYY` and then change the order of the lists as preferred. Make sure single digit months and days receive a leading zero, before finally `joining` the lists back into one string using `-` instead of `/`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['2/18/2020', '9/30/2019']})

df['col'] = (df.col
             .apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[2:] + x.split('/')[:2])
             .apply(
                 lambda x:
                 x[0:1]
                 + (x[1:2] if len(x[1]) > 1 else ['0'+x[1]])
                 + (x[2:3] if len(x[2]) > 1 else ['0'+x[2]])
             )
             .apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x)))
```

---

```
df
    col
0   2020-02-18
1   2019-09-30
```

Comment: Hey @Dharman thanks for the input! I've made some updates! :)

Comment: Thanks this has been helpful!

Comment: @orie anytime! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2/18/2020', '9/30/2019']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
         date
0  2020-02-18
1  2019-09-30
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. But I gotta ask you, why is it that you used a datetime command but it returned a string instead of a datetime object?

Comment: I wanted them as strings, just wonder how the function work hehe